# How to get EnabledSystemUIMode (i.e. system status/nav bar appearing or not), or get notified when the mode is changed in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

In Flutter, we can `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);` to make the app fullscreen (i.e. hide Android system status bar and nav bar).

However, I observed that, if the user manually swipes from bottom of screen upwards, the system bars will re-appear again. The big problem is, Flutter code has no way to notice that. If we can get notified that this is changed, we can, for example, make the "go fullscreen" button appear again, such that users can go fullscreen again when they want.

Therefore, is there any approaches to get the current status of whether the status bar or nav bar is showing? Or even better, can we get a callback fired when it changes?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Oops I find the answer after digging into source code: `setSystemUIChangeCallback`.

It is a bit weird that I did not find it by googling... So anyway I just leave this question here, in case anyone has the same question as me he can find this StackOverflow answer.